# Can anyone help me understand why my MIPS assembly code isn't adding or subtracting correctly?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm writing this simple MIPS assembly code for a class. The idea is for the program to take three inputs: two integers followed by a basic mathematical operator (i.e. '+', '-', '*', or '/'). It performs the indicated operation on the two integers and outputs the result.

Or rather, that's what it's *supposed* to do. However, when you enter a '+' it gives you the difference between the two numbers and when you enter a '-' it outputs their product. Even weirder, multiplication and division work fine! Could someone better than me at assembly language help me understand what's going on here? Thank you!

```
.text
Main:
# Prompt for the integer to enter
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt1
syscall

# Read the integer and save it in $s0
li $v0, 5
syscall
move $s0, $v0

# Prompt for another integer to enter
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt2
syscall

# Read the integer and save it in $s1
li $v0, 5
syscall
move $s1, $v0

# Prompt for operator
Operator:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt3
syscall

# Read the operator and save it in $s2
li $v0, 12
syscall
addi $s2, $zero, 0
move $s2, $v0

# Print ASCII values for debugging
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s2
syscall

# Branch to addition
li $t0, '+'
beq $s2, $t0, Add

# Branch to subtraction
li $t0, '-'
beq $s2, $t0, Subtract

# Branch to multiplication
li $t0, '*'
beq $s2, $t0, Multiply

# Branch to division
li $t0, '/'
beq $s2, $t0, Divide

# Handle unexpected character
li $v0, 4
la $a0, error
syscall
j Operator

Add:
add $s4, $s0, $s1
j Print

Subtract:
sub $s4, $s0, $s1
j Print

Multiply:
mul $s4, $s0, $s1
j Print

Divide:
divu $s0, $s1
mflo $s4
j Print

Print:

# Line break
li $v0, 4
la $a0, br
syscall

# Print 1st value
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s0
syscall

# Print operator
li $v0, 11
move $a0, $s2
syscall

# Print 2nd value
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s1
syscall

# Print equals sign
li $v0, 4
la $a0, e
syscall

# Print result
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s4
syscall

# Exit the program
Exit:
li $v0, 10
syscall

.data
prompt1: .asciiz "\nPlease enter an integer: "
prompt2: .asciiz "\nPlease enter another integer: "
prompt3: .asciiz "\nPlease choose a math operation (+, -, *, or /): "
error: .asciiz "\nNot gonna work!"

br: .asciiz "\n"
e: .asciiz "="
```

My best guess is that it has something to do with the way the branching logic works, but I tried having it print the operation it was doing (e.g. print "adding" when it hit the addition branch) and that seemed to work. It seems to hit the correct branches but somehow perform the wrong operations. I'm at a loss.

Comment: The key concept that you're missing is *branch delay slots*.  The MIPS architecture does not execute instructions in the strict order you'd expect: whenever there's a branch or subroutine call, the next sequential instruction executes BEFORE the target instruction (since that instruction has already been fetched, and there would otherwise be a delay while fetching the new target - might as well make use of that time!).  So after the Add routine does `j Print`, the following `sub` instruction executes before any printing takes place - which overwrites the results of the addition.

Comment: The simplest solution is to just put a `nop` instruction after each branch or call.

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea! Your `nop` solution worked; just for fun I messed around with my simulator's settings and found that the "enable delayed branches" setting was checked, which sounds like it might have been the root of the problem. Thank you, truly, that was driving me crazy.

Comment: @jasonharper Consider writing an answer.

Comment: When branch delay slots are at issue it is important to understand the simulator program/environment.  Both MARS and QtSpim default to "no branch delay slot", though this is an option that can be reversed.

Comment: @jasonharper: Well spotted.  I'm so used to all [mips] questions being about simplified / fake MIPS without branch delay slots that I wasn't even thinking about that.  (Or with an assembler that didn't use `.set noreorder` so the assembler would hide / fill branch delay slots for you.)  For example, assembling this with `clang -c -target mips`, it inserts a NOP after each `j` or `b*`.  A smarter assembler would look for an independent instruction like `add $s4, $s0, $s1` and schedule them into the branch delay slot; perhaps GAS would do that (without `.set noreorder`).

Comment: @PeterCordes, that code is using MARS/QtSpim-style syscalls (which are not used, at least not like that on real MIPS), so suspect popular simulator though the option to use branch delay slots has been enabled somehow.

Comment: @ErikEidt: Oh right, yeah the syscall usage is a dead giveaway.  And yeah, in MARS you just check the "branch delay slot" menu option instead of putting `.set noreorder` in your source, because without that option checked it's not the assembler hiding the branch delay slot, it's the emulator emulating a simplified MIPS; even the binary machine code doesn't reflect a branch delay slot when it's unchecked.  (I know you know this, I'm clarifying for anyone confused by my previous comment.)